# Dynamic font size based on viewport AND text length

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a container whose dimensions are fixed based on viewport, and the text inside of the container is dynamic:

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-container">
    <div>Dynamic length text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.my-container {
    height: 25vh;
    width: 25vw;
    font-size: ???;
}
```

I need the `font-size` within this container to scale accordignly based on the character count of the text in order to prevent it from overflowing. Ideally the text would take up as much space as possible.

I've tried for hours with various **js**/**css** snippets but can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The aim is to get the text to fit, so the font size needs to be reduced until the height is less than or equal to the height of the parent div.

Actually, the aim is to make sure that the area of the div is less than or equal to its parent div. Working with this simplifies things a bit, very few iterations are needed before we get there.

```js
const myContainer = document.querySelector('.my-container');
const div = myContainer.querySelector('div');
const w = myContainer.offsetWidth;
const h = myContainer.offsetHeight;
let fontSize = 25;
// put in an iteration count for the test just in case we end up in some awful loop with War annd Peace being squished in, though it should work in less than 10 anyway
let iterationCount = 0;
function resize() {
  iterationCount++;
  if (iterationCount <= 10) {
    const divw = div.offsetWidth;
    const divh = div.offsetHeight;
    const factor = Math.sqrt((w*h)/(divw*divh));
    if (divh > h) {
      fontSize = fontSize * factor;
      div.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'vw';
      resize();
    }
  }
}
resize();
```

```css
.my-container {
    height: 25vh;
    width: 25vw;
    border-style: solid;
}
.my-container div {
    font-size: 25vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
    <div>
      Dynamic length text and a lot more here so we really overrun Dynamic length text and a lot more here so we really overrun Dynamic length text and a lot more here so we really overrun Dynamic length text and a lot more here so we really overrunDynamic length text and a lot more here so we really overrunDynamic length text and a lot more here so we really overrun Dynamic length text and a lot more here so we really overrun Dynamic length text and a lot more here so we really overrun
    </div>
</div>
```